# Is there certificate storage or something like Keychain on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: certificate, keychain, windows-phone-8

Is there some documentation about how certificates are stored on WP8? (Is there special storage for them like on Android, or are they managed differently?) I cannot find any documentation regarding certificates. I am new to WP8 development and have stucked on this question.

If not certificate storage maybe there is something similar to iOS Keychain that saves information and inside Keychain access group other applications can access it?

Read that there is possibility to encrypt/ decrypt data, but as I understand I can only decrypt them from one application, but I would need to access them also from other applications.
Based on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402533(v=vs.105).aspx and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487164(v=vs.105).aspx

My target is to securely manage data (passwords, certificates) using multiple applications. (Multiple applications can access same passwords etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd party WP8 apps do not have a way to constantly share data with other 3rd party apps. There's no shared DB, Cookie container or read-write file storage that's shared between apps. If that's a feature you'd like to see in future releases feel free to say so on the [WP8 uservoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com).

On the question of certificates it is possible to install custom certificates on WP8 from file storage, email or apps. I've written up an example on how to install custom certificates on WP8 at a related question @ [TLS connection: override certificate validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601799/tls-connection-override-certificate-validation/13617876#13617876)

Comment: Thank you for information! But can I manage (delete) certificates from 3rd party app?

Comment: No. Currently 3rd party apps can only install certificates.

Comment: Is this described somewhere in the documentation? Somehow in documentation I can only find quite general things at the moment. Simply asking maybe I have missed some important part of the documentation or looking in wrong place.

Comment: I'm not aware of any document currently calling out how WP8 is different then iOS and Android from a feature parity perspective.