# Is it possible to import x509Certificates to windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, active-directory, windows-phone-8, x509certificate, x509

Certificate is used to sign pkcs requests or pdf-s created on phone. Is there some mechanizm to do it? 
Can i connect to AD and CA from windows phone app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can email a CER file, download a CER file or launch it from your app and install custom certificates on WP8.

See code sample in a previous answer of mine @ [TLS connection: override certificate validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601799/tls-connection-override-certificate-validation/13617876#13617876)

Comment: Ok. It can be used by any of my apps? Or just allows to connect to Exchange server like in windows phone 7?